# Path has type Object rather than String

Tags: ssl, https, playframework

I am implementing SSL connection for my web application. I have keystore which i am passing while running SBT. But i am getting error "PATH HAS TYPE OBJECT RATHER THAN STRING".

This way i am passing keystore :-

run -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.port=9448 -Dhttps.keyStore.path="certs\example.com.jks" -Dhttps.keyStore.type=JKS -Dhttps.keyStore.password=changeit

I am getting below error :-

```
error] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer  - Cannot load SSL context
ava.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
       at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:103)
       at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:35)
       at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$httpsServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:126)
       at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$httpsServerBinding$1$adapted(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
       at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
       at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.<init>(AkkaHttpServer.scala:124)
aused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRI
       at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:159)
       at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
       at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
       at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
       at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
       at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:34)
       at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:24)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Please tell me if anything wrong in the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception suggest, that one of your path is wrong.

Here is the code, the exception happened:

```
  def createSSLContext(applicationProvider: ApplicationProvider): SSLContext = {
    val httpsConfig = serverConfig.configuration.underlying.getConfig("play.server.https")
    val keyStoreConfig = httpsConfig.getConfig("keyStore")
    val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory = if (keyStoreConfig.hasPath("path")) {
      val path = keyStoreConfig.getString("path") // HERE EXACTLY
```

As you can see it expects a path, called: `play.server.https.keyStore.path`.

It seems that you have configured that path wrong: Check your `application.conf`.

Or adjust your run command.

Comment: yes it worked for me, But my worry is that its not taking properties from application.conf. I had to pass it while running SBT. Can you suggest how could i address this ?

Comment: Just print the config - so you can see it - I never had the problem that application.conf was not read. Except of course you use your own config file: `-Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/my-prod.conf`

Comment: I am starting with SBT run command . May be that could be the issue. But still i need to figure it out how can i pass it to the SBT Shell .Perhaps adding in build.sbt would be help.

Comment: @priyamsingh try `JVM_OPTS='-Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/my-prod.conf' sbt run` in one line (or export `JVM_OPTS` to environment)